# Tribute to a Great Mind

Tags: knowledge, sudoku

This is a puzzle based on an existing Sudoku problem composed by someone else. There are nine regions and each row/column/region must contain the same set of nine different letters:

- {G, R, E, A, T, M, I, N, D}.

The “someone else” is a well-known person in the math and/or puzzle community.

The left diagram shows his Sudoku, except the given clues (letters in the grid) have been replaced with an set of incorrect clues.

***Your task is to deduce the composer’s name, find the correct set of clues  and complete the sudoku.***
This may require some educated guessing, but if you can map the correct clues to a unique solution then it is highly likely you have correctly solved all parts of the puzzle.

EDIT: due to some confusion by many readers, I have done some major editing to make sure there is no reasonable chance of misinterpreting my puzzle. Apologies for any confusion.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm slightly confused. Are you the composer, with the letters of your name incorrect? And is the goal to find a grid that's solvable from the fact the grid currently has incorrect clues? This looks like a very fun puzzle, I just don't understand what we have to do :) Maybe could you give an example?

Comment: The grid with correct set of given clues is a puzzle composed by someone else who is well known in the math and/or puzzling community. I can't remember the source, but I do remember the shapes. I have also double-checked the solution is unique. Unfortunately it's hard for me to give an example without giving away too much.

Comment: When you say one of the clues is correct, are you saying that all but one of the clues is incorrect?  What do you mean it shouldn't appear?

Comment: This question is terribly confusing.  What is that composer you are refereing to?  Are we supposed to see a composer in the riddle?  By composer do you mean a musician or a "puzzle composer".

Comment: I would give a try if this is a pure logical puzzle, for example if there is a unique solution such that all given clues are incorrect, or if there is a unique solution such that all given clues except one are incorrect. But this should be clearly stated, otherwise it might be just a waste of time.

Comment: The edit has made it much better. Thanks

Comment: Before the edit, the puzzle said that all the clues are incorrect (which I took to mean that the letter in that space is _not_ the given one) except for one which shouldn't have been a clue. After the edit, this has changed and the puzzle just says that all the clues are incorrect. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan that was not deliberate. I meant to say the "set of clues" was incorrect. Any individual clue that happens to be correct is just coincidence.

Comment: So, literally the only thing we know at present is that those letters are not _all_ correct?

Comment: I don't see how this can have a unique solution, unless we track down the original on another site. Given just the shapes and no valid clues, it's **possible** that a unique solution is forced (with an arbitrary set of clues across any one row, column or filling one region), but that then gives 9! different mappings of the solution to the 9 given letters, from which any set of clues could be generated to force that unique solution, with many being "meaningful". So first step is to find the puzzle on some other site?

Answer (score 1):

**Partial... initial hunch proved wrong**
[incorporated @JaapScherphuis partial answer given in comments, but no clue how to incorporate it into anything approaching a full answer]

It is clear that

> r1c9 and r2c8 must both differ from every cell from r1c1 to r1c8, because all are in the same row and region.

Which immediately demonstrates

> the given clues are impossible, as one of these is labelled 'N' and the other 'D', but both must contain the same value.

It is also interesting that

> the geometry of the rest of the grid heavily restricts what can appear in various cells, or where certain number can appear in certain regions.

Which initially led me to a sneaking suspicion that

> A unique solution is forced simply by the shape of the grid, and so ANY set of 9 letters, numbers, pictures, etc. can be placed in any row, column or region, to force a unique solution.

So my first attempt was to

> search for solutions where only the first row is fixed - for example starting from
>  [image: GREATMIND puzzle]

However, this ultimately proved false, as

> many millions of solutions are possible even without permuting to different numbers. @WhatsUp stated there were more than 4 * 10^7 (where the top row is fixed), and I aborted my own naive exhaustive search after it had taken more than 24 hours to find more than 800000 and covered only a tiny fraction of the search space.

Taking this from the other side, it was confirmed that @JaapScherphuis correctly identified

> Martin Gardner

as the (purported?) author of the original puzzle. It is undoubtedly important that this name can be made entirely from the letters used in the puzzle.

I modified my exhaustive search program to allow me to try different positions of

> various words including MARTIN and GARDNER in the grid. In cases where the initial position of the clues didn't immediately lead to a contradiction, there seemed to be many solutions. (The first version whose output I posted and retracted had bugs. I think those are fixed now).

These can be reduced further by

> fixing the positions of some words, and trying different positions of others.

There seem too many

> possible positions that starting clues *could* have been given, and too many positions that words *could* appear, to have any reasonable chance at guessing which one the original puzzle creator might have chosen, unless we locate the original puzzle (if that even exists) or have some other way to narrow down the possibilities.

For example, one case where I found a set of words that reduced the possible solutions to 2 was:

> [image: A GAMER MARTIN GARDNER layout]
>  In this position, the MARTIN GARDNER clues had about 188756 valid solutions... adding other words words reduced these, and after trying a few options I got that, whose two solutions differ only in the position of the final 'G' and 'M' near the bottom-right.
>  [image: solutions for A GAMER MARTIN GARDNER layout]

Earlier attempts having

> GARDNER on a diagonal were of limited success, as it becomes difficult to know where to add the extra words for the layouts that don't lead to an immediate contradiction. By having something more contained at the bottom, there was still a decent canvas to play with on the upper half of the grid.

Ultimately this "puzzle" seems to come down to

> Guess what words in what locations the puzzle creator might have used. For now, I stick by my earlier assertion that there are just too many possibilities to make it remotely meaningful as a puzzle.

However, on writing up the answer to this point, it occurs to me that

> the inital attempts using the diagonals were with an older version of my search that were full of bugs... so I'll retry that next.

Comment: I have obtained some result on your "sneaking suspicion" - if my codes are correct...

Comment: @Steve, with a bit of educated guessing one can work out which possible positions should be tested first. I'm thinking this puzzle should add the "enigmatic" tag (since many viewers will expect a puzzle labelled with sudoku-tag to have a clear-cut solution). Would you agree with this?

Comment: @happystar It's not for me to judge what tags are appropriate for a puzzle where I don't yet even know how to approach narrowing down on your intended solution... so far, it's looking like pure guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I got confused by myself ... The result is that there are AT LEAST two different solution.

In fact there are many more ($> 4 \times 10^7$) non-identical solutions, up to permutation of the $9$ letters. Therefore the "sneaking suspicion" of Steve is probably false...

---

This is more like a comment to complement the answer of @Steve, but too complicated to be posted as a comment.

Regarding the "sneaking suspicion" of Steve, I wrote a program and find that there are AT LEAST two possible arrangements such that every row, column and colored region contains $9$ different letters.

Example:

> 123456789
>
>  251367498
>
>  376289541
>
>  637845912
>
>  865794123
>
>  489671235
>
>  948512367
>
>  594123876
>
>  712938654
>
>
>  123456789
>
>  251367498
>
>  376289541
>
>  637845912
>
>  865794123
>
>  498671235
>
>  984512367
>
>  549123876
>
>  712938654

Comment: I suspect that the name formed by the letters is rot13( Znegva Tneqare ), especially given the two loose "clues" in the original grid. However, given the repeated letters in the name, I don't see where it could be placed.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis the second part obviously can't be in a simple straight line. It can be fitted in many ways by wiggling around in various ways, but (with trial and error with Excel doing a substitution matrix) I've not yet found one that leaves unallocated letters in a manner that allows the first part to fit.

Comment: @WhatsUp Are you sure your program is correct? I had a third solution that doesn't match either of your two solutions

Comment: You are right, I was confused because I stopped searching as soon as I found two solutions...

Comment: btw, @JaapScherphuis correctly identified rot13(Znegva Tneqare) as the composer

Comment: Both of your solutions have at least two letters correct in the original clues (M=5).  Perhaps the uniqueness comes from what seemed to be the original constraint that only one letter was correct?